# google maps api ugrade php

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I have a website where I use Google Maps API to see where all my stores are located.

I had php 5.3 and I've updated it to 5.6. But it stopped working. Specifically, I'm getting this error:

```
message: "myMapStreet is not a function"  
name: "InvalidValueError"  
stack: "Error
    at new Ob (http://maps.google.es/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=myMapStreet:43:72)
    at Object._.Pb (http://maps.google.es/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=myMapStreet:43:182)
    at Ig (http://maps.google.es/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=myMapStreet:97:221)
    at http://maps.google.es/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=myMapStreet:162:41
    at Object.google.maps.Load (http://maps.google.es/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=myMapStreet:21:5)
    at http://maps.google.es/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=myMapStreet:161:20
    at http://maps.google.es/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=myMapStreet:162:56"  
__proto__:Error
```

Also i'm getting these warnings:

```
Google Maps JavaScript API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys

Google Maps JavaScript API warning: SensorNotRequired https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required
```

Do I have to update my Google Maps API? But if I have to update it, why is it running fine on my php 5.3?

***INFO:***

- Magento version 1.9.0.1
- PHP version: 5.6

Answer (score 0):

So as i've said since i upgrade my php version 5.3=>5.6 google api stop working. It made no sense because it's js...

So i start watching logs from php and the problem was that i'm getting all my shops info (to print them into google map) from database. And i've seen this error:

> [Wed Aug 22 13:54:53 2018] [error] [client 80.38.218.109] FastCGI: server "/fcgi-bin-php56-fpm-domain.com" stderr: PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /usr/home/domain.com/web/file.php on line 39, referer: domain

So i just update deprecated code and finally worked :)